# How to use default sql expression with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to use default values for a model in rails. The best documented way of doing this that I have seen is using the :default parameter in a migration. However, it looks like this only works for values. I am trying to set a default expression, specifically  `currval('customers_id_seq'::regclass)`. I can add the default expression by hand, but I can't figure out how to tell rails to use a default value. How can I use this default when creating model objects?

**EDIT**
Here is a more specific example:

```
class CreateTestmodels < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :testmodels do |t|
      t.integer :idxfield, :null=>false
      t.string :datafield
      t.timestamps

    end
    execute("ALTER TABLE testmodels ALTER COLUMN idxfield SET DEFAULT currval('testmodels_id_seq'::regclass)")
  end

  def down
    drop_table :testmodels
  end
end
```

With this migration, I can run `insert into testmodels (datafield) VALUES ('sometestdata');`, which will add a row to the table where `idxfield` defaults to `id`.

However, if I run `Testmodel.create(:datafield=>"testdata")` from the rails console, it substitutes null for `idxfield` and throws an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone coming across this now, you can use an expression in a default value migration by wrapping it in a lambda: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/20005

e.g.

```rb
create_table :posts do |t|
  t.datetime :published_at, default: -> { 'NOW()' }
end
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/53804787/479863,  https://stackoverflow.com/q/52788426/479863, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/49659308/479863 but the reference to the pull request is nice.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're trying to use Postgres sequences, which rails will use in all primary key definitions in migrations.

If you need to add it to non-primary key column then you will need to run an ALTER TABLE outside of the `create_table` and add it yourself, like

```
  execute("ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN foo INTEGER default nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)")
```

Comment: I've had success in adding the default fields using execute. However, I can't figure out how to make rails actually use the default when I'm running .create on the model linked to this table.