# Ruby on Rails convention for default to use lambda? default: -> { 'something here' }

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There has been several times answers to some questions online show the use of inline lambda `-> { }` as a value for default in a ruby hash which is given as an optional argument to a method. An example of this is `add_timestamps :model, null: false, default: -> { 'NOW()' }`  or `opt :color, cast: "bool", default: -> { true }`.

I attempted to hunt for this in google, Ruby on Rails Guides but I most likely am not searching the right terms and am not able to find any answers about this.

Edit:

Just want to clarify that I am not looking a specific answer on how to set the default value in the DB to NOW(). I am looking for the theory of when a lambda is the correct tool to use when setting a default value.

Some posts that I have reviewed which did not have the answer:

[When to use a lambda in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232817/when-to-use-a-lambda-in-ruby-on-rails)

[In a Rails migraiton, how do I set the default value of a column to be NOW() instead of the time when I ran the migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49659308/in-a-rails-migraiton-how-do-i-set-the-default-value-of-a-column-to-be-now-ins)

Comment: Based on recent questions, you seem to be interested in `default: ->{...}` with respect to migrations. Hopefully the duplicate clears things up.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "the duplicate clears things up". Is there a question that was asked which already provides the answer to this question which I did not find. If so, could you please provide a link to this.

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate of another question about `default: -> { 'now()' }` in migrations, there's a link to the duplicate at the top of your question.

Comment: Thank you, I reviewed the post that was linked and it does not address my question. I have added some more verbiage to the original post to add clarification.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you don't want Rails to try to interpret the default in any way and just pass something straight to the database (such as `default now()`), yes a lambda. Sorry, I don't remember how I discovered this and I can't find any decent documentation on it.