# How to define the sequence to use when creating a table in ActiveRecord migration in Ruby on Rails 5.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I need to assign a specific Postgres sequence to the ID field of my table. In the model, I tried to define the following setup which has no effect on Posgres:

> class MyObject < ActiveRecord::Base
>
> self.sequence_name = "global_seq"

Usually, a table definition in ActiveRecord migrations start with

```
create_table "objects", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
```

which generates a Postgres definition of column default value as

```
default nextval('objects_id_seq'::regclass)
```

How can I specify in the migration that the nextval() function should rely on another sequence ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the default in a migration:

```
change_column :my_objects, :id, :integer, default: -> { "nextval('global_seq')" }
```

You might want to use `:bigint` instead of `:integer` depending on how your sequence and tables are set up. You have to use a lambda for the `:default` option to get the raw `nextval('global_seq')` expression into the database.

You might want to drop the old sequence as well, AFAIK you'd have to use `connection.execute('drop sequence ...')` for that.

If you're skipping the default `:id` step in your `create_table` then you can do it all when you manually create the `:id` column:

```
create_table :my_objects, id: false do |t|
  t.bigint :id, null: false, default: -> { "nextval('global_seq')" }
  t.primary_key :id
  ...
end
```

Again, the choice between `t.bigint` and `t.integer` depends on how big you want your PK to be.

Comment: The solution is smart but, using Rails 5.1.6, create_table :my_objects, id: false still creates and refers the conventional sequence. I have to apply the change_column anyway.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I don't think Rails creates the sequence at all, it just creates a `serial` or `bigserial` column (depending on version) and lets PostgreSQL create the sequence and set its ownership.

Comment: You are right, as mentionned here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL. What I mean is that the option "id: false" did not avoid the creation of the id column with a serial data type. Or the primary_key data type generated this unique index ...

Comment: Actually, the t.primary_key :id statement is responsible for creating the conventional sequence. I removed it, and it works.

Comment: But then don't you have to manually set the PK with a bit of SQL?

Comment: Yes, the snake bites its tail ... I'll investigate deeper and keep the post updated soon. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid Rails' migrations have no built-in command to set sequence to a column explicitly. It's very database specific.

However it can be done using plain SQL:

```
class ChangeSequenceOfObjectId < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def self.up
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE SEQUENCE global_seq;
      ALTER TABLE objects ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('global_seq');
      ALTER SEQUENCE objects_id_seq OWNED BY NONE;
      ALTER SEQUENCE global_seq OWNED BY objects.id;
    SQL
  end

  def self.down
    execute <<-SQL
      ALTER TABLE objects ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('objects_id_seq');
      ALTER SEQUENCE objects_id_seq OWNED BY objects.id;
      ALTER SEQUENCE global_seq OWNED BY NONE;
      DROP SEQUENCE global_seq;
    SQL
  end
```

If `global_seq` sequence is created in other migration then just remove corresponding lines regarding its creating / deleting.

Also `ALTER SEQUENCE global_seq OWNED BY` commands can be removed if you want to leave `global_sql` sequence as 'free-standing' (staying in the db even if `objects` table is dropped).

Comment: You can do it if you use a lambda for the `:default` option (similarly for setting sane defaults on `created_at` and `updated_at`). There's a fair bit of chicanery involved in any case because Rails really likes to do things its way.

Comment: Wow, I never used ```default``` option in this way. Nice advice

Comment: `:default` didn't work because of the primary_key directive right after it. This worked (in Rails 4.2 as well)

Answer (score 1):

I use `sequence_name` option (Rails 5.1):

`create_table "opjects", sequence_name: 'global_seq' do |t|`

I didn't check, but I guess, in Rails 5.2 it should works too.