# Rails 5.2.3 schema load failing for Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, windows, activerecord, tiny-tds

I have a Rails application that is normally deployed on PostgreSQL databases, but now we have a customer that wishes to use it with a Microsoft SQL Server database.  The schema.rb file referenced below was generated while the application was set up on PostgreSQL.

When I try to create the tables using the **rake db:schema:load** command, it fails when trying to create the primary auto sequence id key field.  It is trying to use an invalid data type of 'serial'.

It's failing on the first table, here is the table in my schema.rb file

```
  create_table "chart_configurations", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "kind", limit: 255
    t.text "display_attributes"
    t.string "primary_measurement_element", limit: 255
    t.string "primary_measurement_label", limit: 255
    t.string "function", limit: 255
  end
```

When I execute the rake command:

```
bundle exec rake db:schema:load
-- create_table("chart_configurations", {:id=>:serial, :force=>:cascade})
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TinyTds::Error: Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type serial.: 
CREATE TABLE [chart_configurations] ([id] serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[kind] nvarchar(255), [display_attributes] nvarchar(max),
[primary_measurement_element] nvarchar(255),
[primary_measurement_label] nvarchar(255), [function] nvarchar(255))
```

SQL Server version 2017
ruby 2.5.8p224 (2020-03-31 revision 67882) [x64-mingw32]
rails (5.2.3)
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (5.2.1)
tiny_tds (2.1.2 x64-mingw32)

Any ideas about what I can do to get my schema loaded?

Comment: "serial" is not a data type in SQL Server, which is what the error message is saying.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define the sequence to use when creating a table in ActiveRecord migration in Ruby on Rails 5.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52788426/how-to-define-the-sequence-to-use-when-creating-a-table-in-activerecord-migratio)

Comment: Alex:  I know that serial isn't a valid data type.  I believe that 'serial' is a Rails convention and will be translated to an auto-incrementing integer specific to the database adapter you are using.  So the serial data type for PostgreSQL creates an integer with a nextval function attached.  I've updated my question to include the fact my Rails application is primarily deployed on PostgreSQL.

Comment: Alex: The other stack issue you reference is interesting and may be useful if I have to create my own SQL Server logic for this.  But in the past, the ActiveRecord adapter handles the database specific things.  An autoseq id field is pretty basic, I'm thinking something is configured wrong in my app.

Comment: What happens if you remove id column from table definition? According to docs one should be created automatically.

Comment: @Alex: I can remove the id column and the table does create. Although the schema.rb file is automatically created after every database change/migration.  It is not meant to be edited. By definition, the *rake db:schema:load* command should be portable against any DB supported by Active Record.   I'll work play around and see if I can come up with a solution that doesn't involve constantly having to edit that file on every database change.

Answer (score 0):

While adding broader database compatibility to a gem I maintain called **[The Brick](https://github.com/lorint/brick)**, had discovered that `serial` and `bigserial` are not honoured by **activerecord-sqlserver-adapter**.  There are a couple of ways to work around this -- either add the option `is_identity: true` when you create a column, or patch the sqlserver gem so that it understands `serial` and `bigserial` and does this for you.

In my case I chose to create a patch for The Brick gem that went in with [this commit](https://github.com/lorint/brick/blob/df3034bd9314d995750520b31c3b8ba6a08a79df/lib/brick.rb#L731-L786), adding overall Microsoft SQL Server support.  If you drop that gem in then it will work -- or you can steal the patch from my code :)