# Rails 5.2 and Active Record migration with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have some attributes that need to have default values. I've set up my migrations to set the defaults in the database as follows:

```
class AddDefaultsToModel < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    change_column :posts, :post_type, :string, default: 'draft'
    change_column :posts, :date_time, :datetime, default: -> { 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' }
  end
end
```

The defaults work great when adding directly to the database. However, if I build a new model in Rails, one attribute works as expected, the other doesn't:

```
post = Post.new
post.post_type # draft (as expected)
post.date_time # nil (expecting the current date and time)
```

Is this behavior deliberate? Do I have to set the default in the model as well? Why does `Post#post_type` work but not `Post#date_time`?

Answer (score 4):

ActiveRecord doesn't understand what your default value for `date_time` means so it doesn't give `date_time` a default value at all. Then, when you insert the row into the database (i.e. `post.save`), the database will use the current timestamp as the `date_time` value (presuming of course that no one has touched `date_time`). Rails won't know that `date_time` has a value after the insert so you get behavior like this:

```
post = Post.new
post.date_time # `nil` because it hasn't been set at all
# set some other values on `post`...
post.save      # INSERT INTO posts (columns other than date_time...) values (...)
post.date_time # `nil` even thought there is a value in the database
post.reload    # Pull everything out of the database
post.date_time # Now we have a timestamp
```

You have some options:

1. Call `post.reload` after saving the `post` to get the default timestamp that the database used.
2. Use an `after_initialize` hook to set the default yourself:

   ```
   class Post < ApplicationRecord
     after_initialize if: :new_record? do
       self.date_time = Time.now
     end
   end
   ```
3. Use the [attributes API](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attribute) to set the default by hand:

   ```
   class Post < ApplicationRecord
     attribute :date_time, :datetime, default: ->{ Time.now }
   end
   ```

   You need to use a lambda (or Proc) so that `Time.now` is executed at the right time.

Comment: I've been using the attributes API but it feels like a bug if I have to define the default twice so I had to ask the question in case I was missing something.

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything, ActiveRecord has a limited understanding of the database so it has now idea what `default current_timestamp` or `default now()` means so you have to do it yourself. And you have to do it twice if you want to be able to insert records without going through Rails.